# How to make billing cycles available as product attributes?

Tags: commerce

On our current billing system (from which we are trying to switch to Drupal Commerce) customers can select a product and then easily select between monthly, quarterly and yearly payment periods. In other words, billing cycles can be selected as product attributes.

And I can't figure out how to make billing cycles available as product attributes on a DC setup. According to the instructions on [Commerce License Billing](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing) products are bound to billing cycle types. Does that mean I have to create three different products (for each monthly, quarterly and yearly billing cycles) for every single good or service product we offer on our website to customers? Doesn't make much sense for websites selling tens different types of services. I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction of configuring this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create different products that are linked to the billing license configurations you want. This means that if you want monthly, quarterly, and yearly billing options, these would each be tied to products and then available via a dropdown.

Comment: I don't like this design as it triples the number of products for each good/service, however since it is apparently the only way of doing it in DC I accept your answer. Thanks.